# How to change the position of a container view within an uiview if the uiview contains subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uistoryboardsegue

I have a UIview and within it a container view. Now the UIview may contain subviews at a given condition.The container view fetches data from another tableview. 
When the uiview is having subviews,it is getting overlapped with the data in the container view,as the latter's position is just at the bottom of the uiview in the storyboard.I need to reposition this container view's frame so that the subviews in the `UIView` doesn't overlap them.I tried to redraw the container view's frame origin whenever the `UIView` is having subviews using `CGRectMake()` but its not showing any changes.I am new to ios so finding it hard to proceed.Any help??

Comment: post the code & maybe a screenshot, then people can help you better. A

Answer (score 2):

Ok now I know what was causing the problem. setFrame:CGRectMake() was not working as because the use autoLayout in the File Inspector box in my main storyboard for the particular view was checked.Thus resizing of view and container view was not taking place.However not making it unchecked works for resizing them,but it changes the layout of all the other views associating with that particular view.I am still working on how to prevent that.Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: I am also having this issue.  I call 'setframe' but it does not adjust it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

To change the frame of container view

```
[containerView setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 20, 20)];
```